# Validation message is not shown for an item with ModelState invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

When I edit a device`s name to empty/null so the ModelState is invalid, how can I return the list of all devices BUT show the one edited device with a validation message that the name must be entered?

At the moment the validation error is only visible over the device table, but I want to show the validation message to the left of the TextBoxFor Helper.

Why is the validation message not visible there?

**VIEW**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCTest.Models.DeviceViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>

        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Device"))
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="background: alice;">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class DeviceController : Controller
    {
        private List<DeviceViewModel> GetDevices()
        {
            return new List<DeviceViewModel>
            {
                new DeviceViewModel{ Id = 1, Name = "Test 1"},
                new DeviceViewModel{ Id = 1, Name = "Test 2"},
                new DeviceViewModel{ Id = 1, Name = "Test 3"},
            };
        }

        // GET: Device
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var devices = GetDevices();
            return View(devices);
        }

        public ActionResult Save(DeviceViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // save to db
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View("Index", GetDevices());
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
  public class DeviceViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a name!")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Name,"")
```

It is using a blank error message as the [specified message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703502(v=vs.118).aspx).

Change it to:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Name)
```

Or:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Name,"A custom error message.")
```

**Update**

You need to return your viewModel back to the view as well instead of creating a new one after the post.

```
public ActionResult Save(DeviceViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // save to db
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

In order for your collection to be posted back to the server you need to use a `for` loop rather than a `foreach`.

See here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

```
@foreach (var i = 0; i< Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Device"))
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="background: alice;">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model[i].Name)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem =>  Model[i].Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id =  Model[i].Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id =  Model[i].Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id =  Model[i].Id })
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
```

I do believe you need to post the collection back to the server as you are saving the data and there is an editable text box here `@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Name)` in your existing code.

Comment: I thought it is taking the ErrorMessage string from my DeviceViewModel?

Comment: @Pascal No, look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703502(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: When I use your:  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Name, "A custom error message.") Then the "custom error message" text is always rendered ???

Comment: @Pascal Yes, you simply replace it. That was just an example.

Comment: @Pascal I would use the first one I suggested i.e. `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Name)`

Comment: I have jquery validation/unobtrusive loaded in my layout and your last advice but when I make the Name empty and save it the modelState is invalid but when the response returns there is no error message at all. I updated my code!

Comment: I can not return my DeviceViewModel back to the View because its not an IEnumerable<DeviceViewModel>. But I need to re-render the list again with the one device + the error message.

Comment: Why the change to for-loop? I do not want to post an IEnumerable<T>. When I return all devices I also want that the empty text which I did not fill is empty AGAIN. Is this doable at all with mvc and a collection at all?

Comment: @Pascal Surely you need to postback the collection as your are saving it and it would have been edited. Correct? In this case you need to use the for loop as model binding will not work with a foreach.

Comment: @hutchonoid No, I save only OR I want to save only a single edited DeviceViewModel.

Comment: @hutonoid Oh right, in that case you need to set assign the viewModel to the one matching your Id in the list. You are re-initializing it back to the one with a name.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have added `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` in your layout.

Add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => item.Name)` and make sure you have added

`@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`

### Edit

You have to add `ModelState.AddModelError("key", "message");`

try to change and see what happen

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

to

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: I did all your suggestions but the error of the Name is not Visible at all. I updated my question with latest code.